# Trying to draw lines from the origin to coordinates in 2D (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

[image]

I'm trying to have 3 lines come out from the centre of the graph at x = 0, going to the coordinates marked by the black dots.

I got the black dots using

```
scatter(X,Y);
```

but can't find a way to have lines emanating from the origin to these dots.

Comment: `plot([0 x1], [0 y1],[0 x2], [0 y2],[0 x3], [0 y3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is fairly easy to do:

```
N = numel(X);
Xlines = zeros(2*N,1);
Ylines = zeros(2*N,1);
Xlines(1:2:end) = X(:);
Ylines(1:2:end) = Y(:);
plot(Xlines, Ylines, '-');
```

This constructs the vectors `Xlines` and `Ylines` by interleaving them with the point `(0,0)`, which looks exactly like what you want.